# Communication between Routers with different CIDER values for Ethernet/Serial Ports

Tags: router, cidr, cisco-ios

I have three Routers, A B and C.
Each Router has the following configurations:
Serial: classA IP/30
Ethernet: ClassC IP/29
Subnets: Two end Devices, ClassC subnet/29
Ip Route is configured using RIP

I can't send data packets from Router A's end device to either Router B or C's end device. 
How do I resolve this?

I've tried to Ping end devices from a different network eg. Router A and Router C, the result is a 100% loss - Request timed out.
PS: I'm doing this on CISCO packet tracer.